# integer sequence that will turn it around

Tags: c#, integer, int, sequence, divide

I have to make a integer sequence that later will turn it around. Example. If the integer is 0,1,2,3,4 it will turn it around in the end to -4,-3,-2,-1,0.

I tried this that the int value i have (mas1) is divided by -1 so it will change the mark on the number. If i tried that i got an error and couldn´t resolve. Error :

> " Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int[]' and
>   'int' "

Here is the code :

```
int[] mas1 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int mas2;
int[] mass = new int[1]{mas1.Length};
Array.Sort(mass);
int arvud = mas1.Length;
int[] koik = new int[arvud];
List<int> list = new List<int>();
foreach (int i in mass)

if (i == mas1.Length) foreach (int a in mas1) list.Add(a);

foreach (int i in list) Console.Write(i + ",");



mas1 / -1 = mas2;
```

Comment: That is possibly the craziest code I've seen. Creating an integer array to hold the length of another array, sorting the one-element array, then iterating over that array checking if the value is the length of the other array?

Comment: why you are using / (division)? You can use * (multiply), will be not throw error.

Comment: If your lists must always be sorted, and contain no duplicates, you could use `SortedSet<int>` instead of `List<int>` and `int[]`.

Comment: @Umesh Well, `arrayReference * -1 = integerValue` (note the assignment `=`) will still be hard to compile. But you're right, multiplication of an `int` by the `int` `-1` will not throw an exception runtime _in `unchecked` context_, while division might.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: It's only for extremely high values that there may be a difference between multiplying and dividing, it's not the cause of the error here.

Comment: @Guffa Agree. I was commenting on a comment claiming that a change from `/` to `*` could be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Using LINQ you can do:

```
int[] mas1 = new []{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] newArray = mas1.Reverse().Select(r => r * -1).ToArray();
```

Or If you want to have negative sign for any number, either positive or negative.

```
int[] newArray = mas1.Reverse().Select(r => -System.Math.Abs(r)).ToArray();
```

If you print it like:

```
foreach (int item in newArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Then the output would be:

```
-4
-3
-2
-1
0
```

You are getting the error because of the line:

```
mas1 / -1 = mas2;
```

You can't divide an array `mas1` with an integer value (-1). I am not sure what you are doing in your code though.

Answer (score 1):

There are some different ways you can do that. You can negate each item and reverse the array:

```
int[] mas1 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] mas2 = new int[mas1.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < mas1.Length; i++) {
  mas2[i] = -mas1[i];
}
Array.Reverse(mas2);
```

You can use a LINQ extension methods to do the same:

```
int[] mas1 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] mas2 = mas1.Select(i => -i).Reverse().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit the array in place, you can efficiently do so like this:

```
int[] nums = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var reverseVal = -nums[nums.Length - 1];
for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
     nums[i] += reverseVal;
```

Assuming the array is sorted as in your example, this code takes the largest number (last element), reverses it's sign to add to each element, which produces the result you want.

And if you want a new array:

```
int[] mas1 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var len = mas1.Length;

int[] mas2 = new int[len];
var reverseVal = -mas1[len - 1];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
   mas2[i] = mas1[i] + reverseVal;
```